# Haskell Shelly sample code

Tags: haskell, shelly

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Shelly (Shell.Pipe) library.
So far i've got:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-type-defaults #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List(sort)

import Shelly.Pipe
import Data.Text.Lazy as LT

default (LT.Text)

findExt ext = findWhen (pure . hasExt ext)
main = shelly $ verbosely $ do
cd bookPath 
findExt "epub" "."
```

I can find all the epub files but then I have no idea how to operate on each of the epub file ?
For example I want to run ebook-convert command on those file names wrapped by Sh Monad.

Btw: The examples are really scarce on the internet...
And it is very confusing that there are two similar libries:Shelly and Shelly.Pipe. The functions inside these two share same name with different Types:
In Shelly.Pipe:

```
find :: FilePath -> Sh FilePath
find = sh1s S.find
```

In Shelly:

```
find :: FilePath -> ShIO [FilePath]
```

Really frustrating !

PS: With the help from [John Wiegley](https://github.com/jwiegley)
I finally got the code working.
I post the code below for people who might use it.
Pay attention to the use of unpack.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-type-defaults #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.List(sort)
import Control.Monad
import Shelly
import System.Directory
import Data.Text
import System.FilePath
default (Text)


bookPath = "/dir/to/books"

main = shelly $ verbosely $ do
    fnames <- Shelly.find bookPath  --fnames can not be processed by normal pure String processing functions and need to be "escaped"
    forM_ fnames $ \n-> liftIO $ putStrLn $ ProcessBookFileName $ unpack $ toTextIgnore n --ProcessBookFileName::String->String
```

Comment: I know I'm a beginner but it's really frustrating to have to dig into the source code just to find out how to use this simple function. I wish people can write just a few more examples when they write libries. Haskell itself already got a bad reputation for being difficult(although ALL haskellers claim it easy)

Comment: Did you see this tutorial? http://www.linux-magazin.de/Online-Artikel/Shell-scripting-with-type-safety-using-Haskell/ It was linked to in Shelly's readme file.

Comment: @MikeHartl I did. It doesn't help a lot and frankly i think it's a joke teaching people how to write script in Haskell without prior knowledge of Monad

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, you don't want to use the `Shelly.Pipe` module, just the `Shelly` module.  The `ShIO` monad implements `MonadIO`, which allows you to execute arbitrary IO actions while inside `ShIO`.  This would let you do something like

```hs
convertEpub :: FilePath -> IO ()
convertEpub fname = undefined

main = shelly $ do
    cd "projects/haskell/testing"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Hello, world!  I'm in Shelly"
    fnames <- find (pure . hasExt "hs") "."
    liftIO $ forM_ fnames $ \fname -> do
        putStrLn $ "Processing file " ++ show fname
        convertEpub fname
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. I somehow got the idea that Shelly.Pipe is an improved version over Shelly

Comment: When I looked at the documentation on Hackage, there was only the `Shelly` module as "public".  What it looks like at first glance to me is that `Shelly.Pipe` is a bunch of internal functions, and `Shelly` is the public interface that uses those functions.  It will probably be a lot more useful to you to use the `ShIO` monad, since it allows you to still do any kind of IO you like, such as converting files, etc.

Comment: @osager It actually looks like I was wrong.  For whatever reason google didn't bring up the latest version of the Shelly library on hackage, so I was looking at a pretty old version.  The documentation says to use the `Sh` monad and the `ShIO` type is being deprecated.  The `Sh` monad is still a `MonadIO`, so you can do IO in it with `liftIO`.  The documentation still recommends using the `Shelly` module instead of `Shelly.Pipes`.

Comment: thank you for taking the time for verifying this. I'm still struggling in and out of those two Monads

Comment: There is something missing from your code, especially two functions:unpack and toTextIgnore.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't run this code (obviously, since convertEpub is undefined), so I'm not surprised that there are issues.  I was more hoping to illustrate how to get the filenames and how to perform IO actions while inside the `Sh` or `ShIO` monads.